# (Python) IndexError: list index out of range when program is working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I use code:

```
username = "How15"
password = "neko"
current = 0
count = sum(1 for line in open("LoginDetails.txt")) #counts ammount of lines
print(count) #just to check ammount of lines
f = open("LoginDetails.txt")
while count<current:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines[current]) #to check contents of the current line
    line = lines[current] #assign current line to a variable
    line = line.replace('\n', '') #remove "\n" from the line
    z = line.split(",") #split "username,password"
    if z[0] != "": #check if username is not blank
        y = z[0]
        if z[1] != "": #check is password is not blank
            y2 = z[1]
    if y == username: #check if username of line = username
        usernamefound = 1
    if y2 == password: #check is password of line = password
        passwordfound = 1
    current += 1 #go to next line
if passwordfound and usernamefound == 1:
    print("Welcome!")
    loggedin = "Yes"
```

but it breaks at "print(lines[current])" with the error message:

```
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
Kri15,shebeg
  File ".../testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(lines[current])
IndexError: list index out of range


Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see it prints out what lines[current] (Kri15,shebeg), but then breaks afterwards. To prove it prints the correct answer here is the contents of "LoginDetails.txt"

```
Kri15,shebeg
How15,neko
\n
```

("\n" just represents a new line)
If anyone has a solution I would be very happy to see it!

Comment: `lines = f.readlines()` should be done once, before the while loop.

Comment: You need the switch the `<` around in your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issue here, I have written suitable comments

```
username = "How15"
password = "neko"
current = 0
count = sum(1 for line in open("LoginDetails.txt")) #counts ammount of lines
print(count) #just to check ammount of lines
f = open("LoginDetails.txt")

#Declare these 2 variables outside the while so that you can access outside
passwordfound=0
usernamefound=0

#Read the file only once and outside the while, this is the big culprit in your code 
lines = f.readlines()

#In question it was '<' I believe it should be '>'
while count>current:
    print(lines[current]) #to check contents of the current line
    line = lines[current] #assign current line to a variable

    #This has to be \\n because othewise \n is considered as escape sequence
    line = line.replace("\\n", '') #remove "\n" from the line

    z = line.split(",")
    if z[0] != "": #check if username is not blank
        y = z[0]
        if z[1] != "": #check is password is not blank
            y2 = z[1]
    if y == username: #check if username of line = username
        usernamefound = 1
    if y2 == password: #check is password of line = password
        passwordfound = 1
    current += 1 #go to next line

#Compare both variables, if they are 1
if passwordfound==1 and usernamefound == 1:
    print("Welcome!")
    loggedin = "Yes"
```

Comment: If you're going to that length, you might as well treat reading the file properly. `with open(...) as f: lines = f.readlines()` and then `count = len(lines)`. Reading the file twice is redundant. And using `sum(1 for ...)` to calculate the len is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Reti43 I wanted to keep code changes as minimal as possible. It helps to find out what actual issue they had in code, especially for beginners.

Comment: Your solution worked altho the line I had a problem with "line = line.replace("\\n", '') #remove "\n" from the line" where "\\n" had to be "\n" otherwise the "\n" at the end of the line wasn't getting removed.

Comment: @Shiru The code has a flaw in general. You assign the username to `y` only if one exists. If you had the line `",password"` in your login details, that would result in a `NameError` when you try to use `y`. Or if this is not the first line, it will use the username from a previous line. Just remove all that `z` nonsense and after `line = line.replace('\n, '').split(',')` simply do `if line[0] == username and line[1] == password:`.